# How do i get 2 query from different table?

Tags: sql

I tried using

```
SELECT segment_name, (select num_rows from all_tables
where tablespace_name='TPCHR'), blocks, extends, bytes 
from dba_segments where tablespace_name='TPCHR'
```

but i am getting single-row subquery returns more than one row.

[image: Question]

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I am trying to select the require columns in a table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including *as formatted text* your table definitions, sample data, expected results, etc.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the tables:

```
SELECT segs.segment_name, tbls.num_rows, segs.blocks, segs.extents, segs.bytes 
  FROM dba_segments segs
       INNER JOIN all_tables tbls ON segs.segment_name = tbls.table_name
 WHERE segs.owner        = 'TPCHR' 
   AND segs.segment_type = 'TABLE';
```